# How to make command run after exit the window in linux

Tags: linux

I am establishing a connection between the linux machine and the another machine to run my scripts.but once i close the window the connection got disconnected.What should i do to make this connection contiue after closing the window.since multiple users execute the scripts in the other machine so its difficult to establish the connection each time..Any suggestions welcome.

the command i wrote in command line to establish connection is

```
     java -jar /home/**/workspace/cli.jar -s https://****** 
     -i /home/**/.ssh/id_rsa -description TESTS 
     -fsroot /home/**/Jenkins -labels test -name TESTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "**&**" after the command to run it in background without need of open windows

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly screen will do. Try 'man screen' in google.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions But i am establishing a connection between  a linux machine and a cloudbees machine i dont think man screen would help me..
I have an idea of running this command as a service so that the connection will be always online could you advice me how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe `nohup` or `batch` could also help.

Comment: tried batch but it says parameters couldnot be passed..in batch